# Can't create a button dynamically with php and js

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm trying to construct a page as a client logs in through php js interaction as fallows

```
$hold = ("< button onclick = `
        function myFunction(){
            alert('works!');
        }
        myFunction();
        ` >My balance</button>");

echo hold;
```

and then i want to send dinamicly to html through js

```
var Permition = localStorage.getItem("Permition");
$.post('MenuConstructor.php',
{ 
    Permition:Permition
}, 
function(data){
    menu = data;
    //alert(data);
    document.getElementById("div").innerHTML = menu;
}
);
```

but for some reson the alert don't work do you guys have any suggestions?
some times i get the error not defined some times i get the error "Unterminated template literal"

Comment: Hello! Please consider exposing the error messages you get, exactly what you expect, etc.

Comment: Why hold holds a dollar sign one day and not the next?

Comment: if `$hold` = a button, then what does `hold` equal?

Comment: $hold is a php variable, is there other way to declare it?

Comment: I gave the error message: "Unterminated template literal"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
"Unterminated template literal"
:) You need escape illegal character.
<div onclick="alert("123")">
<div onclick="alert(&quot;123&quot;)"> // php htmlspecialchars (maybe) (single ' is &apos;) quot with no "e" at it's end 
$url = 'index.html?a='.urlescape($value);
echo '<a href="'.htmlspecialchars($url).'"></a>'
```

Comment: it's very important that javascrip ask to php what should be placed in the html, i can skip this process